# BERTopic model: Should I remove names?

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I am trying to create a movie recommender system, and want to use topic modelling in order to use movie descriptions. Currently, I am exploring the [BERTopic model](https://pypi.org/project/bertopic/)

However, because I have movie descriptions, the output topics uses a lot of names. I want to remove the names in order to increase interpretability, but I was wondering if this will affect the performance of the BERT model.

Sorry, the output is in Dutch, but as you can see there are a lot of names in the topic outputs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It generally should not hurt the quality of the resulting topic representations unless the persons themselves are considered important in the topic representations. In your case, I would argue that that removing names would help creating a more intuitive representation of your topics.

It is, however, important when you are removing names. If you remove them before the embedding step, so before passing the documents to BERTopic, then it might hurt the contextual representation of the embeddings. Instead, I would advise using the [CountVectorizer](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/getting_started/vectorizers/vectorizers.html) to remove these names. You can pass them as stopwords for example. In practice, this means that the names will be removed **after** creating the clusters but **before** extracting the topic representations.

Another step you can take is using [`KeyBERTInspired`](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/getting_started/representation/representation.html#keybertinspired) or [`PartOfSpeech`](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/getting_started/representation/representation.html#partofspeech) as your representation model as they typically remove name-like information.

Source: I am the author of BERTopic.